# Entity Framework won't update newly added properties of an entity

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I've just added few more properties to one of my entities, and now I cannot update them.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Artikal art = db.Artikli.First();            
art.Image = picbyte;
art.BarcodeType = "UAC";
art.Model = "RayBan";
art.StrProperty1 = "aaaa";
art.StrProperty2 = "bbbb";
art.StrProperty5 = "cccc";
db.SaveChanges();
```

`Image`, `Model` and `StrProperty5` are newly added fields, while the rest are"old".

This is what I captured via profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Artikli]
set [StrProperty1] = @0, [StrProperty2] = @1, [BarcodeType] = @2
where ([IdArtikal] = @3)
',N'@0 nvarchar(256),@1 nvarchar(256),@2 nvarchar(16),@3 int',@0=N'aaaa',@1=N'bbbb',@2=N'UAC',@3=1
```

So EF doesn't even try to update those "new" properties.

I just added properties, Model First, Update Database from Model, as I have done many times before.

What could have gone wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Has the database been really updated? Does SSDL contain new properties?

Comment: No, EF wasn't even trying. But it turned out to be quite silly cause. I had turned back my clock a month just a day before I added new properties, and forgot about it. When I corrected it after two days of struggle, everything went back to normal. Though I don't understand why would incorrect clock cause such a thing.